# JQuery Selector overly aggressive on SELECT element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a filterable table using JQuery. My JQuery selector works for my INPUT elements but not for my SELECT elements and I don't understand why -they use the same logic.

The idea here is that we watch the Filter fields at the top of the table for input. Once we see that input we select rows in that column that do NOT contain the data typed in the filter field and hide them.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fw8ur27L/7/)

```
function FilterEverything() {
  $("TR").show();
  if ($("#NumbersFilter").val()) {
    $("input.NumbersData:not([value*='" + $("#NumbersFilter").val() + "' i])").parent().parent().hide();
  }
  if ($("#LettersFilter").val()) {
    $("input.LettersData:not([value*='" + $("#LettersFilter").val() + "' i])").parent().parent().hide();
  }
  if ($("#ColorsFilter").val()) {
    $("select.ColorsData:not([value*='" + $("#ColorsFilter").val() + "' i])").parent().parent().hide();
  }
  $("TR.Header").show();
};
$('#NumbersFilter').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  FilterEverything();
});

$('#LettersFilter').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  FilterEverything();
});

$('#ColorsFilter').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  FilterEverything();
});
```

> why inputs and selects instead of just DIVs?

There are other jquery statements not included here watching these fields for changes and updating a database.

Comment: The `select` element would not match the `[value*=` selector as it does not have a value. The `option`s have the value. The select element does allow the `.val()` property to get the selected options value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$("select.ColorsData:not([value*='" + $("#ColorsFilter").val() + "' i])").parent().parent().hide();
```

with

```
  $("select.ColorsData option:checked").not("[value*='" + $("#ColorsFilter").val() + "']").parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

[JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/yjwjx99p/)

or with

```
var colorsFilterValue = $("#ColorsFilter").val();  
$("select.ColorsData").each(function(i,o) {
  var v = $(o).val();
  if (!v.startsWith(colorsFilterValue))    {
    $(o).parent().parent().hide();
  }    
});
```

[JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/1mq2t7zr/)

Explanation: This iterates over every option item nested in select elements.

```
$("select.ColorsData:not([value*=...])")
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my answer. Could you also upvote my answer ?